# Android - SearchView and overflow MenuItem icon colors

Tags: java, android, toolbar

My toolbar icons are all black, except the `SearchView` and overflow (three dots) icon, which are what appear to be a dark grey color.

[image]

Is there a way to set the tint of these icons to black to match my other icons?

Here's the theme I use, but as far as I know it's nothing out of the ordinary.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.AnglersLog" parent="Base.Theme.AnglersLog">

</style>

<style name="Base.Theme.AnglersLog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:logo">@android:color/transparent</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/anglers_log_light</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/anglers_log_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/anglers_log_accent</item>

    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
</style>
```

And toolbar

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/anglers_log_light"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your styles.xml and any other relavent code?

Comment: There isn't really any relevant code, but I added my theme.

Comment: Could you add `android:theme="@style/yourtheme"` and `app:popuptheme="@style/yourtheme"` to your Toolbar?

Comment: That didn't seem to help, unfortunately.

Comment: OK, add  `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"` to the AppBarLayout and add `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"` and `app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"` to Toolbar. This worked for me.

Comment: That works, thanks you. Write up and answer and I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the theme to the `AppBarLayout` and the `Toolbar` like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Or if you want a dark theme:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:theme="@style/@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```